How to tell whether an Endpoint is an ApiController?
Does an Endpoint obtained from an EndpointDataSource contain any information that identifies the route as an ApiController?
XY: I want an IMiddleware to require a cookie for all requests except API controllers. Currently I'm testing whether the request path starts with "/api", but I wonder if there's a more robust/decoupled way to identify paths that match API controller routes.

The MetadataCollection list returned from endpoint.Metadata contains different entries based on whether an endpoint is an API route or a Razor Page route.
By checking if the MetadataCollection of an Endpoint contains a specific class, you can determine the type of endpoint.



Endpoint
Class to search in MetadataCollection




Razor Page
A Razor Page route contains an entry of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.PageRouteMetadata in its MetadataCollection. An API route will never contain this entry.


API
An API route will contain an entry of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.HttpMethodAttribute in its MetadataCollection list.



Detecting an API endpoint
if (endpoint.Metadata.OfType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.HttpMethodAttribute>().Any())
{
    // This is an API route
}

The HttpMethodAttribute class is defined as:

Identifies an action that supports a given set of HTTP methods.

A MetadataCollection list could contain an entry of type endpoint.Metadata.OfType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RouteAttribute. This entry type, however, will be present only if the endpoint is decorated with [Route("api/mymethod")]. Not all API endpoints have a Route attribute set, as the Route attribute can be set at the Controller level.
Detecting a Razor Page route
if (endpoint.Metadata.OfType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.PageRouteMetadata>().Any())
{
    // This is a Razor Page route
}

The PageRouteMetadata class is defined as:

Metadata used to construct an endpoint route to the page.


This led me to a solution but I'm not seeing either of the metadata types you mentioned. API controller routes actually have ApiControllerAttribute in their metadata. The sample pages in the Blazor Web App template have ComponentTypeMetadata among other types from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints. There's a separate problem of how to match request paths to endpoint routes. My original solution of looking at the path prefix might be best for its simplicity.
